# ValueError: (Django1.11.1 python3.6.1 pycharm)

Tags: python, django, pycharm

When I am trying to log in with the username and password set in the index.html, the error appeared as follow:

```
ValueError at /login_action/
The view sign.views.login_action didn't return an HttpResponse object. It                       returned None instead.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/login_action/
Django Version: 1.11.1
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
The view sign.views.login_action didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
Exception Location: D:\python3.6.1\lib\site-      packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response, line 198
Python Executable:  D:\python3.6.1\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.1
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Administrator\\guest',
'D:\\python3.6.1\\python36.zip',
'D:\\python3.6.1\\DLLs',
'D:\\python3.6.1\\lib',
'D:\\python3.6.1',
'D:\\python3.6.1\\lib\\site-packages']
 Server time:   Mon, 12 Jun 2017 08:29:35 +0000
```

from the hint it said that   the valut of HttpResponse object is none

urls.py  as follow

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from sign import views
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^index/$',views.index),
url(r'^login_action/$',views.login_action),
]
```

views.py  as follow

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.
def index(request):
return render(request,"index.html")
# 登录函数定义
def login_action(request):
 if request.method == 'post':
    username = request.POST.get('username','')
    password = request.POST.get('password','')
    if username == 'admin'and password == 'admin123':
        return HttpResponse( '恭喜您，登录成功!')
    else:
        return render(request,'index.html',{'error':'用户名或者登录密码错误!'})
```

index.html as follow

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>欢迎登陆点米年会发布会系统</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>年会签名系统登陆<br>
    WELCOM TO DIAN MI</h1>
<form method="post" action="/login_action/">
<input name="username" type="text" placeholder="用户名"><br>
<input name="password" type="password" placeholder="登录密码"><br>
    <button id="btn"  type="submit"> 登陆</button>
{{error}}<br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

[the screenshot of the traceback of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHJCl.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your test string to uppercase.  As you can see in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.method the strings for request.method are not lower case.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Better**
   use uppercase letters for method name:

   if request.method == 'POST':
2. **Much better**
   use class based views:

   class LoginAction(View):
       def post(self, request):
          your code

Comment: Totally disagree on point #2 - class based views have their use cases, but they are in now way "better" than function-based views (just like a hammer is not "better" than a screwdriver).

Comment: Mapping http methods to appropriate class methods, raising 405 if method is not allowed, that's what View do. Don't see problem with class based view here.
When I see pattern 'if request.method == 'XXXX'... I think it's much more readable to implement post method in class based view.

Comment: @KePe thanks a lot，it did come from the case problem indeed

Answer (score 0):

Capitalize the `request.method`, like,

```
if request.method == 'POST':
```

Answer (score 0):

The check for "POST" on line `request.method == 'post'` needs to be Uppercase in views.py file.